# Creating anonymous classes in ruby

Tags: ruby, anonymous-class

According to the "well ground rubyist" in the example c "contains" or "points at" an anonymous class. Am I right, that C is not an anonymous class? That's really a little bit confusing.

```
    >> c = Class.new
    => #<Class:0x0000000006c4bd40>
    >> o1 = c.new
    => #<#<Class:0x0000000006c4bd40>:0x0000000006b81ec8>
    >> o1.class
    => #<Class:0x0000000006c4bd40>
    >>
    >> C = Class.new
    => C
    >> o2 = C.new
    => #<C:0x0000000006494480>
    >> o2.class
    => C
```

Answer (score 11, accepted):

- `Class.new` creates a new anonymous (unnamed) class
- `c = Class.new` creates a new anonymous class and assigns it to the *local variable* `c`
- `C = Class.new` creates a new anonymous class and assigns it to the *constant* `C`

Although both assignments look almost identical, there's a subtle but important difference: assigning an anonymous class to a *constant* sets the [`name`](https://ruby-doc.org/core/Module.html#name-method) of that class to the name of the constant:

```
c = Class.new
c.name #=> nil

C = Class.new
C.name #=> "C"
```

This is also mentioned in the docs for [`Class.new`](https://ruby-doc.org/core/Class.html#new-method):

> You can give a class a name by assigning the class object to a constant.

At this point, the class is no longer anonymous. It now has a name and we can refer to it using that name in the form of the constant `C`.

Comment: Thanks, that's it!

Comment: It's perhaps worth noting that [Module#const_set](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.7.0/Module.html#method-i-const_set) can be used to assign an anonymous class `c = Class.new` to a constant: `Object.const_set('C', c); C == c #=> true; C.name #=> "C"`.

Comment: @Cary: Even this works: `>> c = Class.new;
=> #<Class:0x000000000681d9d0>
>> C = c;
=> C
>> c.name;
=> "C"`

Answer (score 0):

The concept of an "anonymous" or "named" class doesn't really make sense in Ruby. A class is just an object like any other object. We don't have "anonymous" or "named" integers or strings either. A class is just an object like an integer or a string: it can be returned from a method, it can be assigned to a local variable, instance variable, class variable, global variable, or constant.

This is different from programming languages like Java with a nominative type system, where a type having or not having a name makes a big difference.

This is really important to understand: a class is just an object that happens to be an instance of the [`Class`](https://ruby-doc.org/core/Class.html) class. Nothing special. It is just an object like an integer or a string or an array.

What classes (actually modules) *do* have, is a method named [`Module#name`](https://ruby-doc.org/core/Module.html#method-i-name), but again, there is nothing special about that method. You can add a `#name` method to your own classes as well.

The only thing that *is* special is that when a class (actually a module) is assigned (whether using the assignment operator `=`, or reflectively using the [`Module#const_set`](https://ruby-doc.org/core/Module.html#method-i-const_set) method) the *first time* to a constant, the path to that constant becomes the return value of `Module#name`:

```ruby
a = Module.new
a.name #=> nil

b = a
b.name #=> nil

module A; module B; module C; end end end

A::B::C.const_set(:D, b)

a.name #=> 'A::B::C::D'

A::B::C::D = nil
A::B::C.send(:remove_const, :D)
A::B::C = nil
A::B.send(:remove_const, :C)
A::B = nil
A.send(:remove_const, :B)
A = nil
Object.send(:remove_const, :A)

a.name #=> 'A::B::C::D'
```

So, as you can see, the distinction between "anonymous" and "named" is practically non-existent, and even if you *could* construct a meaningful definition, then the distinction is still irrelevant.